# How do I theme an aggregator category in Drupal 5.x?

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-5, aggregator

Yes, I am still on Drupal 5. Don't make fun.

I created a category with the Aggregator module, and the URL for the category is `www.example.com/aggregator/categories/2`.  How do I theme this? Is it a node that can be themed with a template, or is there some other process I must use?

edit: To clarify, I want to add some text right below the header, not just theme the individual aggregator items. Sorry, I left that out at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [source](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module?annotate=1.324.2.3&pathrev=DRUPAL-5) (always helpful):

- looking at [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/5), Drupal's "url router", [we see](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module?annotate=1.324.2.3&pathrev=DRUPAL-5#l104) that `aggregator/categories/2` is handled by
- [`aggregator_page_category()`](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module?annotate=1.324.2.3&pathrev=DRUPAL-5#l1069). this function fetches some data and then calls [`_aggregator_page_list()`](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module?annotate=1.324.2.3&pathrev=DRUPAL-5#l1117), which in turn calls
- [`aggregator_page_list()`](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module?annotate=1.324.2.3&pathrev=DRUPAL-5#l1077). this function loops through all feed items (`while ($item = db_fetch_object($result))`) in the selected category and
- *themes them* with `theme('aggregator_page_item', $item)` *

voila, here is your themeing point (theme override), which can be themed with a template (or a custom theme function).

EDIT: themeing / modifying the header seems to be difficult with standard Drupal 5. look at the source again: `_aggregator_page_list()` just concats all (themed) feed items, wraps them in a `<div id="aggregator">`, and adds pager and feed icon - nothing to hook into here. `_aggregator_page_list()` has a optional 3rd argument `$header` which would do exactly what you want - unfortunately, this argument isn't used for `aggregator/categories/2`. so to add some text to the header, you would have to hack `aggregator.module`.

or upgrade to Drupal 6, which added a theme override for the wrapper:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $output .= theme('aggregator_item', $item);
}
$output = theme('aggregator_wrapper', $output);
```

EDIT END

for how to theme Drupal 5, see http://drupal.org/theme-guide/5 , [template.php: Overriding other theme functions](http://drupal.org/node/11811), [Proper theming of aggregator module](http://drupal.org/node/15568), [`theme()` api doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme/5), etc. etc.

good luck!

* and adds some category handling and wraps all the items into one or the other container

Comment: Bah, I missed the theme() function call. I understand that I can use that to theme each individual feed item, but I want to insert some text at the top of the page, right below the header. Is there a way to override the theme_aggregator_page_list function to theme the output of the whole page?

Comment: it should be, but apparently it isn't: theme_aggregator_page_list() seems to be never used (there is no single call to theme('aggregator_page_list') in aggregator.module). see my updated answer for the alternatives.